# How to use firebase / cocos2dx-cpp-sample

Tags: c++, ios, firebase, cocos2d-x

https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample

[image: Image here]

I can not understand this guide. Please teach this process more easily.

I tried ...

1. `cocos new Hello -p com.Hello -l cpp -d ~/Desktop`
2. console.firebase.google.com
3. Add Project > Project Name "Hello", Country Name
4. Add Firebase in ios
5. iOS bundle ID `"org.cocos2dx.hellocpp"`
6. GoogleService-Info.plist DL
7. Add Firebase SDK using cocoa pods
8. Swift or OBJ-C I do not know this. Because I am using C ++. I tried putting the OBJ-C code in AppController.mm but it failed.

I want you to tell me more gently about the explanation of this image. I want to learn by moving the sample as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/firebase-c-and-cocos2d-x-official-guide-from-google-almoust-works-out-of-the-box/35645

Answer (score 0):

You want to run or use [firebase / cocos2dx-cpp-sample](https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample) project

Steps you tried

1. Why are you creating new fresh project, then you need to integrate manually by your self, leave this task to `setup_firebase_sample.py`

// Firebase Console task, I need `GoogleService-Info.plist` for my iOS App

2. Yes you need to register your project
3. Creating Project
4. Add iOS App to your newly created Firebase Project
5. `"org.cocos2dx.hellocpp"`iOS bundle id for Sample project
6. Download `GoogleService-Info.plist` that is needed in my iOS Project
7. Back to step 1. When I downloaded/cloned [firebase / cocos2dx-cpp-sample](https://github.com/firebase/cocos2dx-cpp-sample) project. Project having `setup_firebase_sample.py` that download a fresh cocos project in sample_project folder and Firebase SDK.

After that you only have to open `sample_project/proj.ios_mac/HelloCpp.xcworkspace` file in Xcode and add your downloaded `GoogleService-Info.plist` inside HelloCpp.

8. Leave this step

Done.

You can also check this thread may be some helpful

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/firebase-c-and-cocos2d-x-official-guide-from-google-almoust-works-out-of-the-box/35645